# How could I change the cell output font size in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, font-size

Sometimes I'm running jupyter in a small window, and the output line breaks in two lines, as the example bellow:

[image]

---

Is it possible to reduce the output font size to avoid the line breaking ?